# Only run function on button press

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script which checks for an image and then loads a page if it has been found.

I am trying to attach the function to a button so that it only checks when the button is pressed rather than on page load.

```
<input type="button" id="ImgLoad" value="Check connection">
```

At the moment, the page redirects on load and is not attached to the button press. I'm struggling to see where I've gone wrong with it.

```
<script>  
networkdelay = window.setTimeout(function()
{window.onclick=encaseimage()}, 1000);
</script>

<script>  
clickdelay = window.setTimeout(function(){window.onclick=autoc()}, 
1000);
</script>

<script>

function encaseimage(){

function ImgLoad(myobj){
   var randomNum = Date.now() || new Date().getTime();
   var oImg=new Image;
   oImg.src="http://192.168.8.1/images/ping2.jpg"+"?rand="+randomNum;
   oImg.onload=function(){window.location.href = "/status.html";}

}



networkchecker = window.setInterval(function()
{window.onclick=ImgLoad()},1000);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to load image on button click you need to attach that to the button click event.

like

```
     $("#ImgLoad").click(function(){
       var randomNum = Date.now() || new Date().getTime();
       var oImg=new Image;
       oImg.src="http://192.168.8.1/images/ping2.jpg"+"?rand="+randomNum;
       oImg.onload=function(){window.location.href = "/status.html";}
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the function instead passing the function reference:

```
window.onclick=ImgLoad()
```

Should be:

```
window.onclick=ImgLoad
```

Otherwise the `ImgLoad` function runs immediately.

I should say that adding `onclick` to `window` is probably not the best design (depending on what you are doing).  Usually, you would look up the `button` (by id perhaps) and attach a click handler only to that particular `button`.

On a side note, it looks like the other `window.onclick` events are also setting to the result of calling a function:

```
window.onclick=encaseimage()}, 1000);

window.setTimeout(function(){window.onclick=autoc()},
```

You may want to review those as well. :)